# Registering a service in dot net 6 and using it in Query schema in GraphQL

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, graphql, .net-6.0

I am using GraphQL in my Dot Net 6 project. In my GraphQL Query schema I am calling business layer as:

```
[GraphQLDescription("Get ApplicationParameters")]
public IQueryable<ApplicationParameterDTO> GetApplicationParameter([Service] IApplicationParameterBusiness _applicationParameterBusiness, string appParamName)
{
    var applicationParameterlist = new List<ApplicationParameterDTO>();
    applicationParameterlist = _applicationParameterBusiness.GetApplicationParameterByappParamName(appParamName).Result;
    return applicationParameterlist.ToList().AsQueryable();
}
```

I am trying to register the service in program.cs as:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IApplicationParameterBusiness, ApplicationParameterBusiness>();
```

But when I try to run the project, `var app = builder.Build();` in `Program.cs` gives me following error:

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Shell.OneFps.WSP.Discount.Business.Abstraction.IApplicationParameterBusiness Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Shell.OneFps.WSP.Discount.Business.Concrete.ApplicationParameterBusiness': Unable to resolve service for type 'Shell.OneFps.WSP.Discount.Repository.Abstraction.IApplicationParamaterRepository' while attempting to activate 'Shell.OneFps.WSP.Discount.Business.Concrete.ApplicationParameterBusiness'.)

I even tried changing the dependency injection type to `AddTransient` but still no luck.

What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run this after adding the repository layer dependency and then business layer dependency as:

```
   builder.Services.AddTransient<IApplicationParamaterRepository, ApplicationParameterRepository>(serviceProvider =>
{
    return new ApplicationParameterRepository(serviceProvider.GetService<ITableStorageService>(), serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>());
});
```

and then

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IApplicationParameterBusiness, ApplicationParameterBusiness>();
```